# Shape and background error in Android Studio

Tags: android, background, drawable, shapes

I'm pretty new in Android world and I've encountered a problem. I'm trying to do this pice of code in my first exercise http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape and I have errors without errors. I mean I have red exclamaition mark, but no error message occured. 
And I have no clue, what I am doing wrong. Any ideas? Will be greatful for any help :)
[image: i.stack.imgur.com/id6Rg.jpg]

Comment: Hover over the red error.  What message does it give you?

Answer (score 2):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33032200/4143855) by Youngjae to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33032200/361100) should give you your answer:

> Don't worry, it's for the new Android Studio 1.4, it's appear becasuse there, normally, appear a little icon showing the image from Drawable but if you are using a drawable xml (not being an image), the IDE cannot show a little preview but, don't worry for that error because It's not an error

In short: it's not an error from the code. It tells you that "Android Studio failed to display thumbnail of the given drawable".