# Unknown Warning Icon - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-xml

[image]

**Here's my simple_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

What is the reason behind the appearance of the **Warning Icon**, What am I doing wrong?

I am using **Android Studio v1.4.1**.

Comment: sometimes android studio don't syncronize with our data, like active errors, icon we used, therefore, it seems to be problem in our code, but problem is with android studio, and computer capacities, therefore execute you code and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a no-state item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: put simple_selector.xml in drawable folder.

Answer (score 3):

It's not an error from the code you wrote . It Means Android Studio failed to display thumbnail of the given `drawable`"
visit Here for more:- [unknown exclamatory symbol in the xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33032123/unknown-exclamatory-symbol-in-the-xml-file/33032200#33032200)